# WebApi FromBody object null when one field contains a diacritic

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, diacritics

I have an MVC project that posts to a WebAPI. When an accent character is used (é), the object of the WebAPI [FromBody] is null.  It populates correctly when there are no accent characters.  The MVC object is correct either way, so I don't know why there would be a conversion issue from JSON to my API object. The JSON is generated by Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject version 6.0.1.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", _authorizationString);
    string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);

    var response = await client.PostAsync(_url, new StringContent(json, System.Text.Encoding.Default, "application/json"));
    string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(content);
        TempData["Model"] = model;
        return RedirectToAction("Confirmation");
    }
```

}

```
//API
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage ApiMethod([FromBody] ApiObject obj)
{
    //obj is null here, but only when there is an accent in one of the obj string properties.
    ...
}
```

I just found one more thing.  I can post to the API with Fiddler successfully.  I copied the JSON from this line, string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);

So maybe PostAsync has the error?

Comment: Show the code for your controller action.

Answer (score 0):

I switched the encoding in PostAsync. Unicode and ASCII both worked.  UTF32 did not.